# wemineltc.com Unpaid Shares went back to zero on miner restart

Tags: litecoin, cgminer

I just joined wemineltc it's my first day EVER mining for Litecoin or any other coin for that matter.

So far the side pannel on the wemineltc.com for me says:

```
Your Current Hashrate
43 KH/s It takes 20 minutes for your hashrate to be calculated up to full speed and is only approximate, go by your work utility in cgminer.

Paid Shares All submitted shares from previous rounds which are already accounted and paid for.
Your Valid: 0
Invalid: 0

Unpaid Shares Submitted shares between the last 20 confirms block until now.
Your Valid: 9 
Pool Valid: 5614664 

Round Shares Submitted shares since last found block (ie. round shares)
Pool Valid: Updating...

Round Estimate
1.68E-5 LTC

Account Balance
0.00017 LTC
```

I am using the cgminer and every now and then it says

```
Stratum pool1 0 detected new block
```

and when that happens the side panel increments the number of unpaid shares (Your Valid) it says I have

so I waited until it got to 19 unpaid then in cgminer I pressed [S]ettings & [C]gminer restart when that happened my balance stayed at 0.00017 but my valid unpaid shares now said 0.

now after a while it's back up to 9, **but where did those shares go? Should I have claimed them somehow? Is it automatic  but delayed?**

Comment: I bet your shares got paid, but the amount was less than 0.00001 LTC, so the display amount stayed at 0.00017.

Comment: as David Said, its important to be clear on the difference between shares and payouts they do not equal each other.  a Share == a accepted work towards a solution, however the ammount of of work required to reach a solution may vary which impacts the payout.